# How do I save form response as an object in Django's database?

Tags: python, django

I am unable to save my form responses to the database as an object in Django.
Everytime I click on submit to submit my form, I am just logged out of my website and the object isnt saved in the database either. 
Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong?
This is my models in models.py.

```
class Chain(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    year = models.CharField(max_length=10, default="20XX")
    sem = models.CharField(max_length=30, default="Default Semester")
    code = models.CharField(max_length=10, default="SUB-CODE")
    slot = models.CharField(max_length=10, default="EX+EX")
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

This is my view in views.py file.

```
@login_required(login_url='/')
def create_course(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render(request, 'create_course.html', {})
    elif request.method == 'POST':    
        name=request.POST['name']
        year=request.POST['year']
        sem=request.POST['sem']
        code=request.POST['code']
        slot=request.POST['slot']
        newchain = Chain(
            name=name,
            year=year,
            sem=sem,
            code=code,
            slot=slot,
        )
        newchain.user = request.user
        newchain.save()
        return redirect('success')
```

This is my HTML code for the form.

```
{% extends 'authmain.html' %}

{% block content %}
<h3> <p class="text-center"> Create a new Course Blockchain: </p> </h3>

<div class="card border-dark mb-3 mx-auto" align="center" style="width: 40rem;">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">
      <form method='POST'>
        {% csrf_token %}
        <label for="year">Year: </label>
        <input type="text" id="year" name="year" value=""><br>
        <label for="code">Course Code: </label>
        <input type="text" id="code" name="code" value=""><br>
        <label for="name">Course Name: </label>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value=""><br>
        <label for="slot">Slot: </label>
        <input type="text" id="slot" name="slot" value=""><br>
        <label for="sem">Semester: </label>
        <input type="text" id="sem" name="sem" value=""><br>
        <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" type="Submit"> Create </button>
      </form>
    </h5>
    </div>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

This is my urls.py.

```
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name="home"),
    path('register/', views.register, name="register"),
    path('logout/', views.logoutuser, name="logoutuser"),
    path('dashboard/', views.dashboard, name="dashboard"),
    path('create_course/', views.create_course, name="create_course"),
    path('success', views.success, name="success"),
]
```

This is the view function for success.

```
@login_required(login_url='/')
def success(request):
    return render(request, 'success.html', {})
```

Comment: Can you paste your form code?  And  also are you successfully logging in before attempting this request?

Comment: Why don't you use [ModelForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/modelforms/) ?

Comment: @Dave Form code is in html, do I upload?? Yes I am succesfully logging in, I have no issues except when I try to create a "Chain" object.

Comment: @PanTrakX Would ModelForm prevent the user from logging out and actually save the object? Because I dont understand what I did wrong in my code for it to behave that way.

Comment: @supersaiyajin87 I can't understand why you are logging out from the code you posted but ModelForm would help a lot with what you are trying to achieve!

Comment: @PanTrakX okay, I'll try ModelForm out.

Comment: @supersaiyajin87 You definitely should not be getting logged out. If you post the HTML code of your form I can take a look. ModelForm is a clean way to go but instead of a code revision right now we can see whats wrong.

Comment: @Dave just edited my question by adding the HTML code.

Comment: @supersaiyajin87 your <form> does not have an action mapped to the view you are trying to hit. So I think your getting logged out because its defaulting to `/` for the action path and somehow overwriting your active session. But first thing first give the form a path to the view .  `action='location of view url'`

Comment: @Dave changed it to ```<form action="success/" method='POST'>```, still having the same issue.

Comment: @supersaiyajin87 it shouldn't be `/success` it should be the url to that view. what is the url to the view you created? Upload your urls.py file

Comment: I dont follow, editing the question with the extra code. Please check.

Comment: I changed "success" to "success/", my bad. Still no improvement.

Comment: Your action needs to be `action='create_course/'`.

Comment: I changed it to 'create_course/', still doesn't work.

Comment: can you repost the new html code and also what is failing?

Comment: Can you check my repo out on github? If that's okay.
https://github.com/hpb1/AttenChain-Test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are not closing `form` tag in the `authmain.html`.

```
<ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
  <li class="nav-item">
  <form action="{% url 'logoutuser' %}" method='POST'>
  {% csrf_token %}
    <button class="btn btn-outline-info mb-auto" type="submit">Logout</button>
  -----  CLOSING FORM TAG MISSING HERE ---
  </li>
</ul>
```

and when you submit the form at Create Course, you actually trigger this form, which logs out the user. Add closing tag to the logout form and you'll fix your problem.

Sometimes debugging can be a bit tricky.

Comment: Yes, that fixes the issue. Thanks a ton, I needed this.

Answer (score 0):

To save directly in the database in Django use `Model.objects.create()`

```
Chain.objects.create(user=request.user, name=name, year=year, sem=sem, 
                      code=code, slot = slot)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a model form to achieve this

```
class MyForm(ModelForm):
     class Meta:
         model = MyModel
         fields = []
```

And then you can do something like this:

```
 form = MyForm(request.POST)
 if form.is_valid():
       new_item = form.save()
       ...
```

And it will save directly to the database.